# Object Persistence in Python with many files open

Tags: python, pickle, object-persistence

I'm trying to save the state of my program using pickle, so that I can jump to different states with objects created on a different run.

The issue is that virtually all of these objects (there are quite a few) all have logger objects, so they are all modifying files, and this screws pickling up.

Is there any way to just close all currently open file, so that I can just pickle them?

Comment: When you unpickle to "jump" to a state, what state do you expect or want the loggers to be in?

Comment: If your issue is that the logger instances don't serialize with pickle... maybe you could use a better pickler?  I know that the `dill` pickler can serialize logger instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit what is pickled by including a `__getstate__` method:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    state = vars(self).copy()
    del state['logger']  # remove logger object
    return state
```

You may need to include a `__setstate__` as well in that case, to recreate the logger object.

Comment: All ready tried this. Issue is that logger is also present implicitly in many objects.

Comment: @HX: it cannot be present implicitly; it may be present *inside other attributes* though, like in a list or dictionary. It is still up to your application code to either not reference these on instances or to produce a state that doesn't include them.